# error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘LineLayer&’ from expression of type ‘Layer’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

my compiler complains about this line:

LineLayer& lastLayer = *this->layers.back();

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘LineLayer&’ from expression of type ‘Layer’
```

So he says, that he can't initialize the`LineLayer& lastLayer reference from *this->layers.back()`, which is a vector of Layer* objects (a base class of LineLayer).

Shouldn't it be alright to dereference a pointer and assign it to the reference of a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but not *implicitly*. This is to protect you from undesired conversions, since not every `Layer` is a `LineLayer`. To perform this conversion when you're *sure* that it's valid, use a `static_cast`:

```
LineLayer& lastLayer = static_cast<LineLayer&>(*this->layers.back());
```

If you're not sure whether the `Layer` is a `LineLayer`, use `dynamic_cast`. This will throw `std::bad_cast` if it's not.

```
LineLayer& lastLayer = dynamic_cast<LineLayer&>(*this->layers.back());
```

Going the other way---from derived to base---does not require a cast, and is performed implicitly, because it's a safe conversion.

Answer (score -1):

"Shouldn't it be alright to dereference a pointer and assign it to the reference of a subclass"? Subclass??? No, it shouldn't be "alright", of course. How do you know if that pointer originally pointed to an object of that subclass? Maybe it was pointing to an object of completely different subclass. How do you expect it to work in that case?

If you are sure that the target object has the proper subclass type, you have to explicitly tell the compiler that you really want to perform this dangerous conversion. You have to force the conversion using `static_cast`. Or, if the base class is polymorphic, you can use `dynamic_cast`.

Of course, the real (implied) question here is why do you even want to do that. Do you really need a reference of `LineLayer &` type? Or, maybe, a reference of `Layer &` type would work just as well? There's no way to answer this from what you posted.